# How can I create a linked list of characters read from a file? C language

Tags: c

So I have this homework wherein I have to translate a text from a file into EuroEnglish but I'm stuck at the part where I have to create a linked list of characters. What seems to be missing in my code? I'm still trying to understand how linked lists works so I apologize if the code below isn't written well.

I also would like to ask for a few tips on how I can implement a function that checks each individual characters and apply the rules of EuroEnglish.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void file_contents();
void converted_file();

FILE *fp;   
char c;
int i = 0;

struct L;
struct L
{
    char letter;
    struct L *next;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        printf("USAGE: %s <filename>", argv[0]);
    else
        {
            fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (fp == 0)
            {
                printf("Could not open file.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
            file_contents();
            converted_file();
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
}
void file_contents()
{
    printf("\nYour file contains:\n\n");
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
            printf("%c", c);
    printf("\n");
}
void converted_file()
{
    struct L *first, *tail, *head;
    printf("\nText converted in EuroEnglish:\n");
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        first = (struct L *) malloc(sizeof(struct L));
        first->letter = c;
        first->next = NULL;
            if (tail == NULL)
                head = tail = first;
            else
            {
                tail->next = first;
            tail = first;
            }
    }

    while (first != NULL)
    {
    printf("%c", first->letter);
        first = first->next;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is it a requirement that you should use a linked list? Perhaps it is, so that you can turn "color" into "colour" by inserting a "u" node. (I guess that by EuroEnglish you mean British English.) Otherwise, arrays of chars are the usual way to store strings.

Comment: Yes it is a requirement that I use linked list.

Comment: Suggest you initialize `head` and `tail`.  Find and use the compiler setting to give you warnings about using uninitialized values... and take notice of the warnings.  Suggest `first = head ;` before printing the contents of your list.  `converted_file()` probably does nothing at all after `file_contents()` has sucked `fp` dry.

Comment: Okay I'll try finding a way to modify my compiler settings. I realized what you mean when you said `converted_file()` does nothing when the answer below was posted. Thank you!

Comment: the function: `getc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.  so this declaration `char c;` should be `int c;`

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: regarding: `first = (struct L *) malloc(sizeof(struct L));`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)` this may not recognize EOF. depending on if a `char` is signed (or not) on your C implementation

Comment: regarding: `struct L;` this statement, just before the actual declaration of the struct L is an error.  Suggest removing that statement.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Could not open file.\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "Could not open file." );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("USAGE: %s <filename>", argv[0]);`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);`  Note the trailing `\n` so the message is immediately output to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Best practices recommend to avoid global. Here you have used `fd` as a global variable and opened it in main. Ok until there. Then you read it *until end of file* in `file_contents`. It is still fine, but the file pointer is now at end of file...

When you try to read in `converted_file`, `getc` immediately returns an end of file... But as `fd` is global you did not notice it. This can be fixed by rewinding the file with `fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);`

You have another *rewind* problem inside `converted_file`: after all characters have been read, `first` points to the last character, but you try to display the file content starting from there. You should insert a `first = head;` here, or replace the `while` lop with:

```
for(first=head; first!=NULL; first=first->next) {
    printf("%c", first->letter);
}
```

I have not tried to run it so other problems could remain...

Comment: I get what you are saying and tried it on my code but sadly it still doesn't work. But thank you! I learned and realized a lot of things.

Comment: @Nick: I just addes the fixes described here, and got twice the content of a text file...